# How can I get output from SASM?

Tags: assembly, output, x86-64, nasm, sasm

I am trying to run this program on SASM (based on NASM). The program runs successfully but SASM does not show any output.

```
section .data
msg db "Hello, World!", 0Ah   ; The message to print
msg_len equ $ - msg           ; Length of the message
stdout equ 1                  ; File descriptor for stdout

section .text
global main

main:
  ; Write the message to stdout
  mov eax, 1                  ; System call for write
  mov edi, stdout             ; File descriptor (stdout)
  mov esi, msg                ; Pointer to the message
  mov edx, msg_len            ; Message length
  syscall                     ; Call the write syscall

  ; Exit the program with status code 0
  mov eax, 60                 ; System call for exit
  xor edi, edi                ; Exit status code (0)
  syscall                     ; Call the exit syscall
```

How can I get output from SASM ?

Comment: I have checked your program and it crashes when I tried to run it. By default, NASM uses x86 mode (but most modern computers (except some Mac) is x64 by default). So, I switch to x64 mode and the program has been compiled and I saw the output of the program on the right side of this IDE.